# How to make Eclipse see .jar dropin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have put a .JAR file in my c:/eclipse/dropins folder. This should give me a new option on the context sensitive menu.

It does not.

I can't tell whether this .JAR is even being loaded - can someone help?

The error log does not mention the JAR

This is not a JAR created by me. It is a plugin "UCDetector" I have downloaded from the web.

Does anyone have experience of using UCDetector?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your JAR is an Eclipse plug-in?

A number of thoughts:

- Have you tested your plug-in within Eclipse by creating an Eclipse launch with your plug-in?
- Eclipse doesn't do hot deployment of drop-ins, so you need to restart Eclipse after adding the JAR.
- You can see a list of loaded plug-ins in Eclipse from Window->show view->plugin Registry

Answer (score 0):

UCDetector 1.8.0 does not work with Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.
See: [Can't see UCdetector in Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3422289&group_id=219599&atid=1046865)